# Yii SEO Frienbdly URL

Tags: php, yii

I'm newbie on Yii, I'm facing some difficulties on create Yii SEO Friendly url.

My code is below:

```
echo CHtml::link($Menu->label, array('articles/view',
 'id'=>$Menu->link,
```

This is my view code, currently this url:

```
articles/view&id=75
```

I need this type:

```
articles/75-article_name
```

How can I reach this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add url rule to your config

```
return array(
    // ......
    'components'=>array(
        // ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'articles/<id:\d+>-<t:.+>'=>'articles/view',
                // .......
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And don't forget to add action param `public function actionView($id){}`

Comment: Thanks for think for me but now showing `Property "CUrlManager.articles/-" is not defined.`

Comment: @try it seems that you try append rule right under `urlManager` section, you should add it under `rules` section.

Comment: Hi @SiZE, This work properly, but my another page url is `("articles/view&id=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."")` same site two type link, how can I reach this solution